# Cutting a 2D plane using intersecting planes as a guide

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, knife-tool

Sorry if this seems like a newbie question (I'm very new to Blender!), but what's the easiest way to cut into a mesh using other objects as a guide?

I attached an image for clarity. I want to remove the section of the horizontal plane highlighted in red, using the perpendicular planes as a guide. I tried boolean but just deletes the entire bottom plane. Knife also doesn't seem to be able to use other planes as a guide.

What's the simplest way to do it?

[image: I want to erase the part of the plane highlighted in red]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it is a "cut" question, you can use *knife project* :

- In object mode select the "wall" part <kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Then both select the "floor" part <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd>
- Enter edit mode <kbd>Tab</kbd>
- Place the view to the top ortho <kbd>NumPad7</kbd>
- Then use *knife project* in the tool panel
- Last step : remove the unwanted vertex

[image]

Knife project uses a mesh to cut into another. The cuts are given through the view plane (so it depends on from where you are looking). The cuts are given using the cutting object edges (from this point of view), to create new vertices and edges in the cut mesh.

A step further... this make an ngon (a face with more than 4 vertices) and it is better to avoid ngons...

First approach :

- Enter edit mode
- Select all and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to triangulate
- Then selecting quad parts <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>

[image]

Second approach :

- Remove the ngon face
- Subdivide the wanted edges <kbd>W</kbd> then subdivide
- Place the 3D cursor at the 'pivot vertex'
- Set pivot mode on 3D cursor
- Then move (scale) the vertices to the 3D cursor
- Last : remake the faces <kbd>F</kbd> and eventually correct the normals <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>

[image]

Other possible approaches, certainly...

Comment: Ah, so it's "Knife project" and not "Knife" that I needed! Marked as answered, thank you very much for adding the image